# Calling MSCRM Dynamics On premise login API

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to implement SOAP calls to pull & push information from MS CRM Dynamics but I am not able to find any WSDL or sample calls.

Does anyone know where I can find sample SOAP login call to MSCRM Dynamics? or download WSDL to upload in SOAP UI?

Thanks,
Nitesh

Comment: I just need the SOAP XML which i can execute from SOAP UI tool

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to grab the SOAP for MSCRM calls is either to use a tool such as [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/), or to use the [SoapLogger solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg594434.aspx#BKMK_CaptureHTTPTraffic) in the CRM SDK to write the generated SOAP to file.